# Como declarar correctamente los ViewModels con Jetpack Compose y el patron MVVM

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, mvvm, viewmodel, jetpack-compose

soy bastante nuevo en el desarrollo Android y ahora estoy tratando de desarrollar una aplicación con jetpack compose
usando el patron MVVM.
Basicamente la app está conformada de un solo Activity principal (MainActivity) y a partir de ahí se van llamando los componentes
Composable necesarios para dibujar la interfaz de usuario (Usando para la navegación Navigation Compose).
La aplicación funciona correctamente, sin embargo, mi duda es si estoy declarando correctamente los ViewModels usados por la app.
Ya que actualmente los declaro e inicializo todos en el MainActivity y a partir de ahí se pasan al componente Composable principal, lo cual dudo que sea la forma correcta de hacerlo.
El programa cuenta con 4 ViewModels que son requeridos en distintas partes de la app y queria saber si hay una mejor manera de llamarlos solo cuando sean necesarios.

Adjunto la declaración de los ViewModels que tengo en mi MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity(), EasyPermissions.PermissionCallbacks {
    private val loginViewModel by viewModels<AuthViewModel>()
    private val homeViewModel by viewModels<HomeViewModel>()
    private val suggestionViewModel by viewModels<MakeSuggestionViewModel>()
    private val reviewSuggestionViewModel by viewModels<ReviewSuggestionViewModel>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            AccesibleAppTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
                ) {
                    //Composable que contiene el navigator y la pantalla principal de la aplicación
                    MainScreen(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                        loginViewModel = loginViewModel,
                        homeViewModel = homeViewModel,
                        suggestionViewModel = suggestionViewModel,
                        reviewSuggestionViewModel = reviewSuggestionViewModel,
                        rememberNavController()
                    )
                }
            }
            //isLocationOn(suggestionViewModel)
            prepLocationUpdates()
        }
    }
```

Comment: ¿Por qué crees que deberías *declarar* todos tus ViewModel en MainActivity? Ten en cuenta que los ViewModel son parte de una arquitectura, no los confundas con la UI.

Comment: Si usas Hilt puedes inyectarlos específicamente en cada Screen. Yo los inyecto dentro de cada "rama" (`composable`) que va dentro del lambda del `navigation` y se lo paso al Screen como parámetro. Evita inyectarlos más abajo en la jerarquía porque eso dificulta que puedas crear `@Preview`s.